# Powerquery: passing column value to custom function

Tags: powerquery

I'm struggling on passing the column value to a formula. I tried many different combinations but I only have it working when I hard code the column,

```
(tbl as table, col as list) =>
let 
    avg = List.Average(col),
    sdev = List.StandardDeviation(col)
   
in    
    Table.AddColumn(tbl, "newcolname" , each ([column] - avg)/sdev)
```

I'd like to replace [column] by a variable. In fact, it's the column I use for the average and the standard deviation.

Please any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably does what you want, called as **x=  fctn(Source,"ColumnA")**
Does the calculations using and upon ColumnA from Source table

```
(tbl as table, col as text) =>
let 
    avg = List.Average(Table.Column(tbl,col)),
    sdev = List.StandardDeviation(Table.Column(tbl,col))
 in Table.AddColumn(tbl, "newcolname" , each (Record.Field(_, col) - avg)/sdev)
```

Potentially you want this.  Does the average and std on the list provided (which can come from any table) and does the subsequent calculations on the named column in the table passed over

called as **x = fctn(Source,"ColumnNameInSource",SomeSource[SomeColumn])**

```
(tbl as table, cname as text, col as list) =>
    let 
        avg = List.Average(col),
        sdev = List.StandardDeviation(col)
  in   Table.AddColumn(tbl, "newcolname" , each (Record.Field(_, cname) - avg)/sdev)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The solution works great. 
The function above creates a column with the Z-Score for each column value. 
I was previously trying to use Table.Column instead of Record.Field to pass it but without success. Thx again.